# I can't get image height in css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am writing html-css project. I want to fix header after page scrolls. In codes, header should be fixed after page scrolls as slider image height. But I can't get slider image or slider div height. I share this codes. How can I do this?

HTML

```
<div class="slider clearfix">
   <img class="image" src="images/slider.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fixedMenu{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

JQUERY

```
alert($('.slider').height());
        var sliderHeight = $('.slider').height();
        $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
          if ($(window).scrollTop() > sliderHeight) {
            $('.toppart').addClass('fixedMenu');
          } else {
            $('.toppart').removeClass('fixedMenu');
          }
        });
```

And alert notification is "0".

Comment: try `$('.slider').outerHeight()`

Comment: Result is same unfortunately @Chris

Comment: see [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/objgEd) and alert message of `631`.

Comment: OK, this runs correctly, but what is the problem in my codes according to you ? Already in my codes, when I write alert to other divs, it gives correct height value. But it doesn't give in slider div.

Comment: maybe the code is executed before the image is loaded or the container surrounding the image has a hight of `0`. can you try to build a `codepen ` or `jsFiddle` with your code?

Comment: This portion of code is wrapped with `$(function(){...})` ?